# best practice Java package design

Tags: java, package

I'm currently trying to figure out how to design a small application.
The application is a service, which has some files as an input (excel files or pdf files, which represent reports from 3rd party companies), and its output shall be to generate a pdf invoice from the various reports. These invoices are then sent by hand to the report-issuing company. I know how to make the app do what I want, but currently all classes are in one package "default package". I'd like to change that. So I started renaming the classes, so that they all fit into a metaphore: an "office".
These are my current classes and interfaces:

- OfficeDesk (the hub of kind-of everything)
- Translator (opens pdf and excel files, parses them into a String)
- Report (an object which represents the content of a pdf or excel report file)
- ReportBook (a list of all Reports)
- BookKeeper (converts report Strings into Reports, adds Reports to the ReportBook, implements ReadingSkill)
- ReadingSkill (interface, forces BookKeeper to be able to convert a String into a Report Object)
- TypeSetter (some general String utilities)
- Typist (converts ReportBook into a pdf, uses TypeSetter, implements InvoiceTypingSkill)
- InvoiceTypingSkill (forces Typist to implement methods such as TypeReportTable(), TypeDueDate(), etc..)
- JobAgency (a service which briefly looks into a pdf file to decide from which source (reporting company) the pdf is, and then provides a specialised BookKeeper (a sub-class of BookKeeper, f.e. WeylandCorporationBookKeeper for a bookkeeper who knows how to read reports from Weyland Corporation) or Typist for the job)

With this I have lots of classes that need to use ReportBook and Report, which I was planning to put into the package  "filingcabinet". So now BookKeeper imports filingcabinet. Typist does too, etc...
How can I package this, so that packages don't need each other? Or actually is it good practice that they use each other?
f.e.

1. BookKeeper.writeRecordToBook( ReportRecord Record, ReportBook Book )

versus

2. BookKeeper.writeRecordToBook( String[Object] Record, Vector Book )

I think (1.) is more readable, but forces BookKeeper to have a dependency. With (2.) on the other hand, there is no dependency, just common java types, but less readable. What is better practice here? Also how would you name the packages (or should there only be one, with such small amount of classes)

My current packages are

- office (classes: OfficeDesk)
- filingcabinet (classes: ReportBook, Report)
- services (classes: JobAgency, Translator, TypeSetter)
- services.bookkeeping (classes: BookKeeper, ReadingSkill, all BookKeeper sub-classes)
- services.typist (classes: Typist, InvoiceTypingSkill, all Typist sub-classes)

I realise this could have been written in a more concise example, but thanks for reading and for any input / opinion!

Comment: I usually follow [this structure](http://stepaheadsoftware.blogspot.nl/2012/06/java-package-name-structure-and.html). It's in no way an actual reference, because there are no reference, but it helps.